# Full website logo on sharing post on facebook

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a wordpress site and when i share its post on facebook ,I could not get full image properly(half image is only visible)
Below is the screen shot.

[image]

below is the og tag i have used for it,

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/>
```

where `$img_src` is my logo to be displayed.
Is there any method through which i can fix this and can show full image as logo

Answer (score 0):

Resize your image!

> Small Images
>   If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in the link page post, but the size will be much smaller.

More info at Facebook [website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)

Comment: hey khairoul thanks for your reply.The image i am using right now is 300*112 pixels by size.Do i need to make it more smaller?
Although facebook says image size should be minimum 200*200 pixels ,I have tried image of 224*224 pixels but in that case facebook crawler couldnot fetch the image in some of my post.

Comment: well, it might be your image that is too low in resolution. try using difference resolution and see the result